# executing a stored proc with datareader instead of dataset

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain to me how I could convert this sample function to use a DataReader instead of a DataSet?

```
private void Example(int pIntValue1, pIntValue2)
{

DataSet dsExampleResults;

int i = 0;


using (var daExample = new SqlDataAccess(this.ConnectionString))
{
var cmdExample = daExample.GetStoredProcCommand("Example.dbo.GetExampleData");

                    daExample.AddInParameter(cmdExample, "@param1", DbType.String, name);
                    daExample.AddInParameter(cmdExample, "@param2", DbType.DateTime, date);

                    dsExampleResults = daExample.ExecuteDataSet(cmdExample);
                }

                if (pIntValue1 >= pIntValue2)
                {
                    i = dsExampleResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                    while (i > 0)
                    {
                        i--;
                        decExampleColumn1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dsExampleResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["column1"]);
                                    decExampleColumn2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dsExampleResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["column2"]);

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    i = 0;
                    while (i < dsExampleResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                    {
                        decExampleColumn3 = Convert.ToDecimal(dsExampleResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["column3"]);
                        decExampleColumn2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dsExampleResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["column2"]);

                        i++;
                    }
                }

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how it would loop through the row count with a datareader. I know I can change dsExampleResults to SqlDataReader drExampleResults, and then ExecuteReader instead of the data set. But processing the returned data is where im hung up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get have a method on your SqlDataAccess class to return a datareader, you simply use

```
While (dataReader.Read())
{
        decExampleColumn1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["column1"]);
        decExampleColumn2 = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["column2"]);
}
```

Remember you need to expicitly close SqlDataReaders otherwise they will consume a database connection until garbage collected

Comment: `using` statements are your friend, as far as closing data readers and such.